# I'm trying to write a function which is defined as parameter in C

Tags: c

I have to write a program about fibonacci series. The program should have two functions. One function to read user input and one function to print fibonacci sequence and how many numbers were printed (length of the sequence). In addition, the function to print the fibonacci sequence should define a parameter to accept the user input.

There is my program, please help me check it and help me do the rest of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Fibonacci(int);

int main()
{
int num;
printf("enter a number:\n");
scanf("%d",&num);
if (num < 0) {
printf("invalid user input, enter a positive number\n");
} else {
Fibonacci(num);
}
return 0;
}

int Fibonacci(int num)
{

int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 1;
int totalNum = 2;
int next;
printf ("%d,%d", num1, num2);
next = num1 + num2;

while (next <= num)
{
printf(",%d", next);
num1 = num2;
num2 = next;
next = num1 + num2;

}
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I want to print how many number were printed. Furthermore, I want to print the output to the text file name "myprogram.txt"

Answer (score 0):

For how many numbers printed in function just take a variable counter and intialize it to 2 (as pre-calculated) `counter=2` and then keep on increment it inside while loop 
something like this

```
fabonacci(....)
{
 .
 //rest of code
 //
  counter=2;
  while (next <= num)
  {
       printf(",%d", next);
       num1 = num2;
       num2 = next;
       next = num1 + num2;
       ++counter;
   }
   printf("\n%d\n",counter);
 }
```